# Sorting by custom date type with DataTables

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, datatable

I use [DataTable](http://datatables.net) library in my web application. I have custom date format, so my sorting doesn't work. Can anybody help me? So, this is my date field:

```
<td><fmt:formatDate value="${doc.docDate}" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"></fmt:formatDate></td>
```

Libs:

```
<script src="/resources/jquery/moment.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/dt/DataTables-1.10.11/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="/resources/dt/DataTables-1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/dt/DataTables-1.10.11/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/dt/DataTables-1.10.11/js/datetime-moment.js"></script><!--date format sorting  https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18-->
```

Datatables initialization:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'dd/MM/yyyy' );
        $('#main-table').DataTable();
```

But sorting doesn't work: [image: Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataTables has inbuild functions for sorting. You may have to use a plugin for your date format to sort properly. This may prove useful: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/

Comment: I have already read this article. I try some like this: ` $('#main-table2').dataTable({
            "columnDefs": [
                { "type": "datetime-moment"  }
            ]
        } );` . But result is same

Comment: Everythig seems in order. Are there any errors in your browser console

Comment: Sorry. Try chaging format to "DD/MM/YYY" in momet call

Comment: Thank you! This is works. `$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD/MM/YYYY' );
        $('#main-table').DataTable();`

Comment: Glad it works. You can check this link for moment date format: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Answer (score 0):

i've made custom my datatables date format like this :

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    "aaData": data,
    "order": [[2, "desc"]],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { sType: "date-custom", aTargets: [0] } //based on your date column
    ],
    "aoColumns": [
        {"mDataProp": "date_save"
            ,"mRender": function(data, type, full)
            {
                var getData = new Date(data);
                var month = getData.getMonth() + 1;
                var date = getData.getDate();
                var year = getData.getFullYear();
                var hour = getData.getHours();
                var minute = getData.getMinutes();

                return (date > 9 ? date : "0" + date) + "-" +
                       (month > 9 ? month : "0" + month) + "-" + 
                       year + 
                       ", " + 
                       (hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour) + ":" +
                       (minute > 9 ? minute : "0" + minute);
            }
        },
        {"mDataProp": "source_page"},
        {"mDataProp": "sub_status"}
    ]
});
```

jquery plugin with some customize :

```
$.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
"date-custom-pre": function(a) {
    var x;
    try {
        var dateA = a.replace(/ /g, '').split("-");
        var Datetime = a.replace(/ /g, '').split(",");
        var timeA = Datetime[1];//time hour:minute
        var timeB = timeA.replace(/ /g, '').split(":");// split hour & minute
        var hour = timeB[0];
        var minute = timeB[1].replace(/\D/g, '');// remove string after "hour:minute"

        var day = parseInt(dateA[0], 10);
        var month = parseInt(dateA[1], 10);
        var year = parseInt(dateA[2], 10);
        var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute);
        x = date.getTime();
    }
    catch (err) {
        x = new Date().getTime();
    }

    return x;
},
"date-custom-asc": function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
},
"date-custom-desc": function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
}});
```

it will show like this :

```
15-12-2016, 12:33
```